# Looking to create a simple for loop that allows the user to use the TAB key on dropdown menu items

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, for-loop, accessibility

Looking for help on creating a simple FOR Loop that allows the user to use the TAB key on dropdown menu items. **For accessibility purposes.**

At the moment, the user can use the tab key, but it will only enable the first active dropdown menu that's in order. The next couple dropdowns do not automatically show? If it helps, i'm using WordPress.

Here is my JS

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
menu.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Tab") {
    document.querySelector(".sub-menu").style.display = "block";
  } else {
      document.querySelector(".sub-menu").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
            <nav class="mainmenu">
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-5635" class="menu-item">
                    <a href="/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-6017" class="menu-item"><a title="Events" href="">Events</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-30109" class="menu-item">
                            <a title="" href="/calendar">Events Calendar</a>
                            </li>
                             <li id="menu-item-5719" class="menu-item">
                            <a title="" href="/calendar">Tours</a>
                            </li>
                             <li id="menu-item-5661" class="menu-item">
                            <a title="" href="/calendar">Host Your Event</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Side note, having menus/submenus open automatically by tabbing to them, while not a [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) (Acccessibility) violation, it **does** cause a UX issue related to accessibility in that it makes it harder for the user to tab across the main menu and get to the last item in the menu because the user is forced to tab through all the submenus (because they open automatically) before reaching the last main menu item. This is even more difficult for users of [sip-and-puff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sip-and-puff) type devices.

Comment: It's better to have a separate focusable element that the user can press ENTER on to open a submenu, or allow the down arrow to open the submenu, rather than opening the submenu automatically. To see an example of a separate focusable element, see https://equalizedigital.com/.  (I don't have any connection to that website but found it the other day and noticed the main menu.)

Comment: @slugolicious This is super helpful and good for us to note. By chance, are you able to assist on the for loop part? We might still want to do this approach near term while adding in an arrow next to the dropdown items.

Comment: When you say *"the next couple dropdowns do not automatically show"*, are you talking about the next dropdown on the main menu or do you mean a submenu of a submenu? It looks like you have "Home" and "Events" on the top menu and that "Events" has 3 items in a submenu. When you TAB to "Events", is the submenu opening?